# How do I split an array based on object strings that contain a specific character?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I currently have an array with various different tags and I want to be able to split the array depending on whether or not the object within the array contains a specific character.

Currently the array is like this:

```
var tagArray = ["<div>", "<div class="extra">", "<h1>", "</h1>", "<h3>", "</h3>", "</div>", "<p>", "</p>", "</div>"]
```

What I want to be able to do is create a function that can split the array into two separate arrays depending on whether or not the string contains the `/` character

Comment: Like [Lodash `partition`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#partition)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you want to split the `tagArry` into 2 new arrays, one that contains all strings which include the / character and the other array should have the elements without the / character? If that is indeed what you are trying to do, that is fairly easy with the `filter` method.

```
    var tagArray = ['<div>', '<div class="extra">', "<h1>", "</h1>", "<h3>", "</h3>", "</div>", "<p>", "</p>", "</div>"];

    const arrWithSlashElements = tagArray.filter(e => e.includes('/'));
    console.log(arrWithSlashElements);

    const arrWithoutSlashElements = tagArray.filter(e => !e.includes('/'));
    console.log(arrWithSlashElements);
```